# Are the HTC Desire HD video issues solved yet/solvable by the end user?

Tags: video, htc-desire-hd

I'm considering getting an Android phone, and at the moment, my choice is between the HTC Desire and the HTC Desire HD. As the price difference is minimal, the obvious choice would be the newer one, but some reviews have mentioned [video issues](http://www.techradar.com/reviews/phones/mobile-phones/htc-desire-hd-717295/review?artc_pg=7) on the device.

Since that looks like an issue that could be solved in software, and that review was written at the time of release. Are these issues still present on fully update HTC Desires, and can they be solved if they are?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess these issues are solved as I have never encountered such on my Desire HD.

Answer (score 0):

There are solutions if you encounter problems (which I did myself).

One thing to try if you get "laggy" or "jagged" video is to disable USB debugging or uninstall the flash updates from market.

I'd imagine this issue doesn't occur on the latest batch of devices; my friend's just got the DHD and it's working fine.